# Baked texture is way darker than render in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, baking

I've been searching for quite a while for a solution but can't seem to find what I'm doing wrong or if it's even possible.

I have a scene with models which are all fitted with materials (just diffuse colors) just the way I like it. I've been rendering until I was satisfied with the way it looked. My plan was then to bake everything so that I had a texture that resembled the render so I could use it in a game engine.

Now the result is disappointing because the baked texture is way darker than the render itself. I think it maybe has to do with ambient occlusion settings? If I uncheck Ambient Occlusion, the result stays the same.

What am I doing wrong? (images attached)

Thanks in advance!

[image: Quick render with right colors]
[image: Baked texture applied (much darker)]

Comment: Welcome to Blender.se! If you are using the object in the BGE you should add  more information about how you are handling lighting in the scene and the kind of material you are using. To show up texture's real color in 3D view you should enable *shadeless* option.

Comment: You are viewing your texture probably in **shaded view**, so the texture get's darkened by the shading. You need to view it without shading.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is (probably) that you are using a non-zero "Roughness" value on your diffuse material. The Roughness part of a diffuse material can't be baked because it's view-dependent. I.e. it changes depending on where you're viewing it from, which means you can't bake that information to a texture. Set your roughness values to zero, and things should work perfectly.

If not Roughness, think about other view-dependent features you might be using, and see if those are what's causing the difference.  Some examples are any glossy shader (even with a high roughness), Fresnel data, velvet shaders, and (obviously) reflections. Some of this information (like reflections) CAN be baked, but it has to be mapped a little differently than just a regular texture.

A screenshot of your node setup for your Cycles materials would help me be more specific with my recommendations, but not necessary.

Yvain makes a good point that if you're just doing a diffuse material, you might not have to bake that to a texture. You could just use a material in-game. You can, however, bake the AO and put it on top of an in-game material to make it look better.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

What you want is setting up your scene for the game engine ? If you dont use any texture then the only thing you need to bake is the ambiant occlusion pass and shadows and use them for diffuse intensity. Also you can't use AO option in the game, it is only affecting the view port.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried baking just the ambient occlusion now. Getting closer to what I want to achieve. I was making it way too difficult for myself :)